# AlamofireObjectMapping Error: Cannot call GET

Tags: ios, swift2, realm, alamofire, object-object-mapping

**UPDATE**

My POST request in Login.swift returns values that I would like mapped to the variables in Particulars.swift (E.g. the API token) and by extension, written to realm. How do I go about doing so?

My Login.swift code:

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
import RealmSwift
import ObjectMapper
import AlamofireObjectMapper


class Login {


init(userName: String, passWord: String) {
    Data.sharedInstance.userName = userName
    Data.sharedInstance.passWord = passWord
}

// call this method to login
func getRequest() {

    Alamofire.request(.POST, Data.todoEndpoint, parameters: ["username": Data.sharedInstance.userName!, "password": Data.sharedInstance.passWord!])
        .responseJSON { response in

            if let result = response.result.value
            {
                let value = JSON(result)

                    if let api_key = value["api_token"].string
                    {
                        print("The token is " + api_key)

                    }

                    else
                    {
                        print("error parsing api token")
                    }

            }
            else
            {
                print("JSON data is nil.")
            }


    }

}


}
```

---

I am trying to map my JSON requests to Realm but I keep being thrown this error

> Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred

This is what I am looking for: (all in separate files)

send GET requests -> store in realm/ create new object if it does not exist/ update object

How can I fix it?

[image: Error calling GET method]

**Code to call GET request**  (full code here https://codeshare.io/l4cEQ)

```
FetchData.get(Particulars.self, success: {
                            print("success!!!")
                    }) {
                         print("fail!!!")
                    }
```

**Code to process GET request**

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import ObjectMapper
import AlamofireObjectMapper
import RealmSwift

class FetchData {
static func get <T:Object where T:Mappable,T:Meta> (type:T.Type,success:()->Void,fail:()->Void)->Void {
    Alamofire.request(Method.GET, type.url())
        .responseArray { (response: Response<[T], NSError>) in
            switch response.result {
            case .Success:
                let items = response.result.value
                if let items = items {
                    let realm = try! Realm()
                    try! realm.write {
                        for item in items {
                            realm.add(item, update: true)
                        }
                    }
                    success()
                }
            case .Failure(_):
                fail()
                break
            }
    }
}
}
```

**Code to map objects** (Particulars.swift)

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift
import ObjectMapper

protocol Meta {
static func url()->String
}

class Particulars: Object, Mappable {
dynamic var name = ""
dynamic var email = ""
dynamic var id = 0
dynamic var profilePicture = ""
dynamic var username = ""
dynamic var apiToken = ""

override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "id"
}

//Impl. of Mappable protocol
required convenience init?(_ map: Map) {
    self.init()
}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    id    <- map["id"]
    name <- map["name"]
    email <- map["email"]
    profilePicture <- map["profile_picture"]
    username <- map["username"]
    apiToken <- map["api_token"]
}

//Impl. of Meta protocol
static func url()->String {
    return "https://bitbucket.org/hyphe/blog-examples/raw/master/fetchData/demoapi/books"
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `Particulars` class doesn't declare its conformance to `Meta`, and so the typechecker doesn't consider it a valid input to your `get` method. You need to declare the conformance explicitly; just having the required methods isn't enough:

```
class Particulars: Object, Mappable, Meta {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Actually in my Login class, the POST response would give me the values that I am looking for. Is there a way for my to directly map it to the variables in the Particulars class? (I've updated my answer to show this)